# Calling Fortran routines in scipy.special in a function jitted with numba

Tags: python, numba

Is there a way to directly or indirectly call the Fortran routines that can be found here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/special/cdflib and that are used by `scipy.stats` from a function that is supposed to by compiled by `numba` in `nopython`mode?

Concretely, because `scipy.stats.norm.cdf()` is somehow pretty slow, I am right now directly using `scipy.special.ndtr`, which is called by the former. However, I'm doing this in a loop, and my intend is to speed it up using `numba`.

Comment: You can use ctypes or cffi (see http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#cffi) to call external functions. You'd need to work out the Fortran to ctypes conversion though - I'm not sure I could do it off the top of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at [rvlib](https://github.com/QuantEcon/rvlib), which uses Numba and CFFI to call RMath, which is the standalone C library that R uses to calculate statistical distributions. The functions it provides should be callable by Numba in `nopython` mode. Take a look at the README for an example of the function that is equivalent to `scipy.stats.norm.cdf()`

If you're still interested in wrapping `cdflib` yourself, I would recommend using CFFI. You'll have to build a C-interface for the functions you want. You might find this blog post that I wrote helpful in getting started:

https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/calling-c-libraries-numba-using-cffi

Comment: Funny, I actually read your blog post before posing the question and wondered whether there is an 'easier' path. I did not know about `rvlib`!

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the normal CDF, then you can implement it using the `erfc` function in the standard library's `math` module.

```
import numba
from math import erfc, sqrt

SQRT2 = sqrt(2.0)

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def normcdf(x):
    # If X ~ N(0,1), returns P(X < x).
    return erfc(-x / SQRT2) / 2.0
```

You can probably vectorize it using `numba.vectorize` instead of `numba.jit`.